How to insulate space between ceiling and roof
I bought a house where someone converted the attic into a bedroom and they did a great job of insulating the walls but didn't do anything between the drywall and the roof. Today was 80 degrees and while the rest of the house was 70 degrees that bedroom was 87. Is there a method of insulating that doesn't require me to take down the drywall?

One way is to use blown-in insulation, where you drill small holes in the drywall and blown in loose fill insulation with a machine.
But normally a roof should be ventilated, where a common method is to have vents in the eaves and on the ridge of the roof, with a continuous path between the two.  Blowing in loose insulation would completely fill that cavity blocking all air flow and reducing the effect of that insulation by preventing the hot air from escaping the underside of the roof.
A less than optimal way would be to cut slots in the drywall and shove rigid foam panels that sit on top of the drywall and leave space between the foam and the underside of the roof deck.  But that is kind of a lot of work for not so much insulation. Plus you still have to repair the slots you cut.
Another way would be to wait until the roof needs to be replaced, and tear off the roof surface and add insulation from above.
With these option on the table, taking down some drywall is not sounding like such a bad option.

Good point, I need a roof anyway. I’ll have it all done at the same time.

Cutting slots and repairing may be more work than simply replacing the drywall entirely.  The latter will also give you a lot more working room for the insulation and vent installation.

You can use blown-in insulation, This requires a bunch of patchable holes in the drywall to get access to put the nozzle in. At least one per cavity.
Though you will need to check on the vapor barrier requirements, it's no use blowing in insulation and then having that rot away or become saturated with moisture.

The vapor barrier is a concern I didn’t even consider, thanks!
